# sql server 2008 connection string error

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection-string

I know this is a quite standard issue... but can't figure it out..

So here's what i want to do:

I want to connect to my local sql server .\SQLEXPRESS by windows authentication. I can login by using the SQL Server Management Studio.

My connection string is like this:

```
string connStr = "Provider=SqlOleDB;Data Source=.\\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=Sports; Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

it throws me an error:

```
Cannot open database "Sports" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

so i tried:

```
string connStr = "Provider=SqlOleDB;Data Source=.\\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=Sports; Trusted_Connection=True";
```

it gives me:

```
Invalid authorization specification
```

Then i tried:

```
string connStr = "Provider=SqlOleDB;Data Source=.\\SQLExpress; Initial Catalog=Sports; Integrated Security=True";
```

it returns:

```
No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).
```

Any ideas??

updates: i forgot to mention, i'm using virtual machine windows 7 running the sql server 2010 express. Is there anything to do with the virtual machine???

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with http://www.connectionstrings.com ??

I would try something like:

```
Server=.\\SQLExpress;Database=Sports;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

That should work, I hope (no need to specify a provider and all that stuff).

Comment: i tried most the combinations from the http://www.connectionstrings.com website. And if i didn't add the provider, it gives me an error telling me that i need to specify the provider. This connection string works fine when i connect to the server, but not works fine when i want to connect to the local.

Answer (score 0):

Yo,

Do u use some IDE? Like VS2008? First, try restart SqlServer in your Configuration Manager.